# Using EPSG:27700 Projection with OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, geojson, bng

I want to use OpenLayers to use it with GeoJson Vector layers from MSSQL Spatil Table which have projection of UK coordinates BNG based on Easting Northing.
Also which basemap can i use if not OpenStreetMap due to the different Coordinate system.

```
proj4js.defs('EPSG:27700','+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 '+'+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy '+'+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 '+'+units=m +no_defs')


const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM(),  //OSM is OpenStreetMap
});

const source = new ol.source.Vector();

const vector = new  ol.layer.Vector({
source: source,
style: new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 155, 155, 0.4)',
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#ff0000',
    width: 2,
  }),
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 7,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#ffcc33',
    }),
  }),
}),
});

const map = new ol.Map({
layers: [raster, vector],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
  //Want to use Projection from EPSG:27700  but dont know how add this projection to Openlayers Projection list
 //center: [-11000000, 4600000],
 center: [-198896, 7103661],  //Huddersfield(UK): [-198896, 7103661]
  zoom: 12,
}),
});
```

Comment: How do you load you vector source? That part of code is missing, and that's where you reproject GeoJSON `EPSG:27700` to standard OSM `EPSG:3857`.

Comment: OSM can be reprojected to EPSG:27700 as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection.html  If you don't want to use OSM there are Ordnance Survey maps available, the ESRI hosted source used as the EPSG:27700 overlay in that example is available without an API key but has limited detail at some zoom levels, or you can get an API key from OS at https://osdatahub.os.uk/ for more options.  In your code you need to register proj4 `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);`